# Music21 to get sample of time and frequencies in txt or csv

Tags: python, frequency-analysis, music21

I'm getting familiar with python but I just discovered [music21](http://web.mit.edu/music21/doc/moduleReference/moduleAudioSearch.html) and even if I'm currently reading as much as possible from the documentation, I'm having a hard time finding simple answer to my simple question:

> How to sample a piece of music (say from a .wav or .aup file) for a specific rate to get both time and frequencies (or log2),  eventually using [music21](http://web.mit.edu/music21/doc/moduleReference/moduleAudioSearch.html)?

The idea here would be to specify the rate (say every 0.1 second) and get the lines.

```
Time, Frequency
.1,441.223
.2,441.266
.3,441.488
etc.
```

I'm guessing the music21.audioSearch.autocorrelationFunction tool should be okay but not sure if I understand exactly what it does...

If it helps -- **my goal is** to put those pieces of music through computational analysis in order to understand the fluctuations of the frequencies relatively to several factors coming from the performance and the performer.

So I'd need to print this to a .csv or .txt at some point in order to save data.

Thanks beforehand for any clues you may have for me ;-)

Comment: Music21 is a library for working with musical scores not audio files.

Answer (score 1):

As Michael said, music 21 only works with symbolic notation, not audio. Librosa is a python library that works with audio files, but it is very difficult to isolate exact pitch and offset information from an audio signal. To look at analysis of performance differences, check out the Magenta project by Google. They had pianists perform on a midi keyboard and did machine learning to model the expressiveness.

Comment: Thanks I'll look at that and tell you ;-)